# Pandas - Best way to derive a new column by checking condition on other rows of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["GroupType"] = ["Group_1","Group_2","Group_3","Group_1","Group_2","Group_3",
                   "Group_1","Group_2","Group_3","Group_1","Group_4","Group_4","Group_4"]
df["ID_1"] = ["10","10","10",
              "10","10","10",
              "10","10", "10",
              "12","12","12","13"]
df["ID_2"] = [pd.NA,"100",pd.NA,
              pd.NA,"200",pd.NA,
              pd.NA,"300",pd.NA,
              "400","400","400",pd.NA]
df["Price"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
df
   GroupType ID_1  ID_2  Price
0    Group_1   10  <NA>      1
1    Group_2   10   100      2
2    Group_3   10  <NA>      3
3    Group_1   10  <NA>      4
4    Group_2   10   200      5
5    Group_3   10  <NA>      6
6    Group_1   10  <NA>      7
7    Group_2   10   300      8
8    Group_3   10  <NA>      9
9    Group_1   12   400     10
10   Group_4   12   400     11
11   Group_4   12   400     12
12   Group_4   13  <NA>     13
```

The requirement is to derive the 'Actual Price'.
Logic is if 'GroupType' == 'Group_4' then get 'Price' from the matching Group_1 with same 'ID_2'. For example row 9 above is the matching 'Group_1' record for rows 10,and 11.
And if 'GroupType' != 'Group_4' then populate just 'Price'.

Expected Dataframe:

```
   GroupType ID_1  ID_2  Price  Actual_Price
0    Group_1   10  <NA>      1             1
1    Group_2   10   100      2             2
2    Group_3   10  <NA>      3             3
3    Group_1   10  <NA>      4             4
4    Group_2   10   200      5             5
5    Group_3   10  <NA>      6             6
6    Group_1   10  <NA>      7             7
7    Group_2   10   300      8             8
8    Group_3   10  <NA>      9             9
9    Group_1   12   400     10            10
10   Group_4   12   400     11            10
11   Group_4   12   400     12            10
12   Group_4   13  <NA>     13            pd.NA
```

My solution:

```
def get_linked_actual_price(
        x: pd.Series, source_df: pd.DataFrame
):
    mask = (source_df["ID_2"]== x["ID_2"]) & (source_df["GroupType"]== "Group_1")
    if not mask.any():
        return pd.NA
    source_df = source_df.loc[mask]
    if len(source_df.index) > 1:
        source_df = source_df[:1]
    result_series = source_df.squeeze()
    return result_series.get("Price", pd.NA)

group_4_mask = df["GroupType"] == "Group_4"
df.loc[~group_4_mask,"Actual Price"] = df.loc[~group_4_mask, "Price"]
df.loc[group_4_mask, "Actual_Price"] = df.loc[group_4_mask].apply(get_linked_actual_price, axis=1, source_df=df)
print(df)
```

My concern is since I am using the apply on each row this is not performatic.
So wanted to check if there is a better solution in terms of performance?

Comment: In solution I use Group_1 because the requirement says match with Group_1. And if you see where the function is called - it is applied only for rows where Group_Type == "Group_4".

Comment: I got almost what you have expect `Actual_Price` for number 12 is `13`. How did you get `pd.Na`?

Comment: Row 12 can have 13 only if it was not of type Group_4. Since its Group_4 the logic from the function is applied and returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this problem

- Mask the values in `Price` where `GroupType` is not equal to `Group_1` then  group the masked column by `ID_2` and `transform` using `first`
- Update the values in `Price` column where `GroupType` is `Group_4` using the values obtained from `step 1`

```
m = df['GroupType'].eq('Group_1')
s = df['Price'].where(m).groupby(df['ID_2']).transform('first')
df['Price'] = df['Price'].mask(df['GroupType'].eq('Group_4'), s)
```

---

```
   GroupType ID_1  ID_2  Price  Actual_price
0    Group_1   10  <NA>      1           1.0
1    Group_2   10   100      2           2.0
2    Group_3   10  <NA>      3           3.0
3    Group_1   10  <NA>      4           4.0
4    Group_2   10   200      5           5.0
5    Group_3   10  <NA>      6           6.0
6    Group_1   10  <NA>      7           7.0
7    Group_2   10   300      8           8.0
8    Group_3   10  <NA>      9           9.0
9    Group_1   12   400     10          10.0
10   Group_4   12   400     11          10.0
11   Group_4   12   400     12          10.0
12   Group_4   13  <NA>     13           NaN
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works like charm. But could you please elaborate this? s = df['Price'].where(m).groupby(df['ID_2']).transform('first'). Did not understand this fully.

Comment: @PuneethR Glad it worked! here is the breakdown of the code statement 1. `df['Price'].where(m)`: Replace the values in `Price` column with `NaN` where `GroupType=Group_1`.  2. `.groupby(df['ID_2'])` : Group on `ID_2` column, 3. `.transform('first')`: Get the first non-nan value per group and broadcast across entire group

Comment: Great. Thank you.